# Смещение ui объекта в сторону gameObject'а

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется карта, на ней кликабельный gameObject. Когда я нажимаю на него у меня появляется подсказка (ui элемент). Мне необходимо чтобы подсказка во время нахождения камеры над/рядом gameObject'ом находилась рядом с объектом. Но когда камера уходит от объекта, то ui элемент сдвигается к границе и остается там, до того момента когда gameObject не появится в кадре снова и подсказка не "прилипнет" к нему.. Т.е. ui элемент должен быть рядом с краем, до того пока не объект не появится в кадре, независимо от передвижения камеры.

[image: tooltips]

Прошу подкинуть идей реализации или подсказок в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить ГО **Renderer.isVisible**

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

Если да, то находишь координаты ГО на экране
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html

а затем перемещаешь туда свою подсказку. И держишь ее там пока ГО виден(с движением камеры нужно обновлять и позицию подсказки).

Если нет, то двигаешь подсказку к границе.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что стоит копать в сторону [OnBecameInvisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html), [OnBecameVisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html), а также в сторону [Screen](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html), а точнее в сторону его атрибутов **height**, **width**, возможно сразу **resolution**.

То есть в `Update()` при определённом условии вызывать подсказку, а в `OnBecameVisible()`, `OnBecameInvisible()` проверять показывается ли сейчас подсказка, и если да, то задавать ей расположение относительно размера экрана, например (ну или найти центр и относительно него задавать расположение).

А, вообще, я бы очень рекомендовал ознакомиться с UI, введённым в версии 4.6. У Unity есть прекрасный раздел Learn, в котором есть раздел [обучающие материалы](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials) (tutorials). [Тут](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) можно найти уроки по UI.

Дело в том, что был введён Canvas (холст), который позволяет настроить расположение UI элементов на себе относительно камеры и выбрать как они будут вести себя: фиксировано располагаться, растягиваться вместе экраном и т.д. Посмотрите уроки, рекомендую. Ну или загляните в [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-Canvas.html)